# If I giveaway half of my wage saving to my parent, Is there any chance that my wife could ask some of this back after divorce?

Tags: united-states, divorce

If I giveaway half of my wage saving to my parent, Is there any chance that my wife could ask some of this back after divorce?

Show your reference from authentic sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gifts that are sincerely given away are generally not part of the assets to be split up in a divorce.

However, if you transfer assets to a parent, only to start receiving that value back from them after the divorce, this is considered hiding assets and is illegal

- [Whatever the reason, hiding assets, income and debt is not only unethical; it’s also illegal and subject to severe penalties IF discovered.](http://www.forbes.com/sites/jefflanders/2012/03/14/divorcing-women-heres-where-husbands-typically-hide-assets/#4187aa20665d)
- [You’ll likely be deposed, which means you’ll have to provide live testimony, under oath, about assets and property. If you lie during discovery or your deposition in order to hide assets, you’ve committed perjury (a punishable crime).  If your lies are discovered by your spouse, your spouse’s attorney, or a judge, you may face severe sanctions (monetary fines) or a perjury charge.](http://www.divorcenet.com/resources/divorce/before-after-divorce/attempting-hide-assets-before-divorce#)
- [in some states, you can even be arrested for very serious incidences of hiding assets](http://info.legalzoom.com/penalty-hiding-assets-divorce-25071.html)

Comment: Thank you but What if it is for home mortgage on a legacy that will be pass to me?